# Passing LINQ element as parameter to another .xaml wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to send the result of a LINQ query as parameter to another .xaml file in WP7.
 If yes then can you please explain via an example.
 Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("VideoContent.xml");
var content = from query in xml.Descendants("Video") where (string)query.Element("Clip") == parameter 
              select new Video() { File = (string)query.Element("File") }
```

Now I need to pass the string in File to another .xaml using NAvigationService.

P.S I am very new to WP7 and LINQ

Comment: LINQ query or result of LINQ query ? What is the format of your LINQ ?]

Comment: yes result of the LINQ.
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("VideoContent.xml");           
var content = from query in xml.Descendants("Video")
              where (string)query.Element("Clip") == parameter
              select new Video()
              {
                File = (string)query.Element("File")
              };
Now I need to pass the string in File to another .xaml using NAvigationService.
P.S I am very new to WP7 and LINQ

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the string value, you can pass it as the Navigation parameter.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewPageName.xaml?file="+content.First().File, UriKind.Relative));
```

and then in the OnNavigatedTo handler of the New Page, get the 'file' string value like this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string file; //declare this before the page constructor

        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("file", out file);
    }
```